# Apache2 config not redirecting all requests on port 80 to 443

Tags: ubuntu, curl, apache2, redirect

I have apache2 configured on my web server:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2016-07-14T12:32:26
```

I'm trying to redirect all of my HTTP traffic to HTTPS:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

My config is working fine, however, I ran into the following issue:

```
> curl -IL "http://example.com/"

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2017 14:44:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://www.example.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2017 14:44:25 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=10
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=604800
Content-Length: 226
Content-Type: text/html
X-HW: 1493131465.dop004.la2.t,1493131465.cds052.la2.shn,1493131465.dop004.la2.t,1493131465.cds025.la2.c
Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Feb 2017 17:05:44 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Accept-Encoding
GEO: US
ETag: "e2-548a8cec41423"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY

> curl -IL "http://www.example.com/"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2017 14:42:57 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=10
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=604800
Content-Length: 226
Content-Type: text/html
X-HW: 1493131377.dop006.la2.t,1493131377.cds025.la2.c
Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Feb 2017 17:05:44 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Accept-Encoding
GEO: US
ETag: "e2-548a8cec41423"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

As you can see in the above cURL my web server is redirecting non www HTTP traffic to www HTTPS just fine, however, when I attempt the same redirect from www HTTP to www HTTPS it fails and on shows a 200 when I should get a 301.

Any suggestions at this point would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was due to my CDN. I've since made the appropriate policy changes and my web servers redirect is now working.